# What causes this runtime internal error about "previous declaration at" when building with Go 1.14 after upgrading from Go 1.13?

Tags: go

After upgrading my `go` installation folder to `Go 1.14`

```sh
sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.14.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

I am receiving a runtime error every time I try to build a program:

```
~/playground/go/src/hello  go build hello
# runtime/internal/atomic
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:18:6: Load redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:16:24
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:24:6: Loadp redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:22:32
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:30:6: Load64 redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:28:26
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:36:6: LoadAcq redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:34:27
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:41:6: Xadd redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:39:37
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:44:6: Xadd64 redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:42:39
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:47:6: Xadduintptr redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:45:47
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:50:6: Xchg redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:48:36
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:53:6: Xchg64 redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:51:38
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:56:6: Xchguintptr redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:54:45
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:56:6: too many errors
```

I tried to downgrade to version `1.13.8` and `build` and `run` go fine.

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/go && sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.13.8.linux-amd64.tar.gz

~  go version
go version go1.13.8 linux/amd64

~/go  go build hello && go run hello
hello, world
```

My OS is Linux Mint 19.2.

Comment: That is strange. Saw similar stuff if the old installation was not removed _completely_ before installing the new one. So try removing the whole /usr/local/go, make sure there is no go lurking around anymore and install 1.14.

Comment: I had the same issue and the answer bellow was able to solve it. I think this question should not be marked as off-topic. It seem to be a problem that happens when someone updates Go to version 1.14

Comment: I am having identical problem, why is this question closed?

Comment: I reproduced the problem and found the cause (explained in the answer). Should the question be reopened? @Flimzy

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why you're asking me, but since you did, here's my opinion: This is a common question, so re-opening it will probably result in it being closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Flimzy I'm asking you because in the private feedback is reported "Closed last month by Flimzy." Anyway it's not a big deal since people can read it even if it's closed :-)

Comment: It was closed by three people, only one of whom was me. :) And re-opening it requires three votes, too.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This error is reproducible and occurs when the target directory has been already used for older **Go** installations and some files have been renamed (compared to previous version).

For instance:

in **Go 1.13.8** file `go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go` has been moved to `go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go` in **Go 1.14**.

Extracting without cleaning target directory triggers "**previous declaration**" error because `func Xchguintptr` is declared both in `go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go` and `go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go`

To avoid this type of error remove the installation folder (**/usr/local/go**) and reinstall **Go 1.14**.

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/go && sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.14.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

Test again:

```
~/go/src/hello  go version
go version go1.14 linux/amd64
~/go/src/hello  go build hello && go run hello
hello, world
```

Comment: I found this problem previously too.  It comes about if you just unpack a go1.14 archive over the top of an existing /use/local/go setup.  Some of the files were renamed so you get both the old files and the new 1.14 files in the same GOROOT directory which confuses things.  If you make sure you delete the /usr/local/go contents before unpacking it avoids this.  Please consider updating your answer to include the explination of what leads to the problem at the end.

Comment: I don't know what I did differently, but this is a lifesaver. +1

Comment: This helped. I was installing Go 1.15 on Windows 10 today and it seems there were still leftovers from a previous Go version. I removed the C:/Go folder and ran the 1.15 installer again - after that, the problem was fixed.